# How to prevent system from creating system logs?

Tags: apex, debugging

Each and every day while using the dev console, I run into the message that we have over 1GB of logs, which slows down the dev console and prevents us from setting our own debug trace flags.

The funny thing is, these logs are system-generated. They did not stem from a debug trace flag, and no logs are visible in the debug logs page. They seem to be generating based on the system's native design.

**These logs are making me pull my hair out at this point**. I regularly use data loader to export/delete them (which is the most efficient way I know of), but will sometimes see the logs have gone past 1GB again **one hour later**!!!

SF support tells me that this would be a matter for their developer support which my org does not have access to, so unfortunately they cannot help.

Does anyone know whether I have any control over these system logs being auto-generated? I would like to just turn them off if at all possible.

Here is an image with some exported examples if that helps:

[image]

Comment: Salesforce logs what you tell it to, check in the debug-logs section on setup to see which ones are active. Try not to activate any debug log on any user running batches or heavy integrations, mass data loads, etc. Otherwise you will get those logs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Developer Console automatically sets a TraceFlag on your user, so while its open, it's logging. You can't really prevent this except to not use the Developer Console, as it always has a TraceFlag configured while open. You can minimize the size of the logs via Debug > Change Debug Log Levels... and setting everything to the NONE detail level. You can (and should) also clear out your logs when you're done with Debug > Clear > Log Panel.

Comment: That all sounds right - I constantly have the DC open for various reasons. Thanks so much for the answer once again sfdcfox! I also have several recurring scheduled/batch jobs that run under my user. I'm going to cancel those and generate them under a different admin user to mitigate the sheer number of logs.

Comment: Thanks again sfdcfox! Always appreciate your quick and thorough answers. It was definitely a result of having the dev console frequently open as determined through testing. Interestingly though, even when clearing the logs in the console as you suggested there are still leftover logs in my name that can be exported using data loader, but aren't visible in the DC or debug view - not sure what to make of that (no manual trace flags set). Either way, this equips me with the tools I need to live with just a little bit less stress :)

Comment: One more discovery - by setting all debug levels to NONE, this effectively does disable the creation of DC logs altogether. It seems that SF recognizes the worthlessness of creating empty logs :) I've NEVER experienced such smooth usage of the dev console before - this is like upgrading from windows 95! Thanks again.

Comment: @BrigLarimer Oh, that's good to know. Glad I was able to help.